# Applying a function by row to certain columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset with a number of columns. I have a function that creates the standard error taking n and r, to do so.

I wish to apply this function to each row of my dataset, and for it to take column 11 as n, and column 15 as r. Then apply my function to these two columns, for each row of my dataset. And then to save the output as a new column in my dataset.

```
r.se = function(r, n) sqrt((1-r^2)/(n-2))
```

is my function code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function arguments are vectorized, so the columns can be directly applied as arguments

```
r.se(df1[, 15], df1[, 11])
```